# Listing Data from 2 different tables/models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display listing in a view page taking data from 2 different tables/models.

(Table1)Table_Service:

1. Id
2. Name

(Table2)Table_Request:

1. Service_Id
2. Description
3. Requestor
4. Status

Table1 & Table2 are link by Id/Service_Id.

My view page should be the (Table2)Table_Request listing :

1. Service_Id
2. Name(From Table1)
3. Description
4. Requestor
5. Status

My view page is as per below:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlinePlatform.Models.ServiceRequests>
<section class="section">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Please choose a service to start</h2>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>System Owner</th>
                            <th>Created By</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>@item.Id</td>

                                <td>@item.Id</td>
                                <td>@item.ServiceId</td>

                                <td>@item.Name</td>

                                <td>@item.RequestorId</td>
                                <td>@item.Description</td>
                                <td>@item.Status</td>

                                <td><button type="button" class="btn">Edit</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller is as per below:

```
public ActionResult Service_Request()
    {
        var dao = new ServicesDAO();
        return PartialView("Service_Request", dao.ServiceRequestGetAll().ToList());
    }

public IQueryable<ServiceRequests> ServiceRequestGetAll()
    {
        var result = DB.ServiceRequests.OrderBy(r => r.Id);
        return result;
    }
```

How do i display the Name which is taken from (Table1)Table_Service?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Sorry to ask this silly question but what do you mean ASP.NET Core? Is there a difference between asp.net mvc and asp.net core?

Comment: there is ASP.Net MVC 1 - 5 and then MVC Core 1 and 2, there is subtle differences between them all, but if youre trying to get two different classes or objects into a single view you want to consider having a viewmodel that brings in both of the viewmodels \ models that you want to work with so that they are both in scope at the time you need them

Comment: either that or bring it through in different partials

Comment: To @SimonPrice, i tried using a viewmodel that combine both of the viewmodels/models but then i encounter this error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OnlinePlatform.Models.ServiceRequests]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[OnlinePlatform.ViewModels.Services2ViewModel]'."

Comment: The difference should be explained better in another topic. I just want to know which one to post an answer for your question.

Comment: @TânNguyễn i believe i'm using ASP.Net MVC 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want mixed result set returned as `IQueryable<T>`, the `Join()` query should be used and put query results in a viewmodel:

1) Lambda version

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceRequestsVM> ServiceRequestGetAll()
{
    var result = DB.ServiceRequests.Join(DB.Services,
                                         x => x.Service_Id, // Source table foreign key
                                         y => y.Id, // Joined table primary key
                                         (x, y) => new ServiceRequestsVM { Id = x.Id, Service_Id = x.Service_Id, Name = y.Name, Description = x.Description, Requestor = x.Requestor, Status = x.Status })
                                        .OrderBy(z => z.Service_Id).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

2) Query expression version

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceRequestsVM> ServiceRequestGetAll()
{
    var result = (from srv in DB.Services
                 join srq in DB.ServiceRequests
                 on srv.Id equals srq.Service_Id
                 select new ServiceRequestsVM
                 {
                     Id = srq.Id,
                     Service_Id = srq.Service_Id,
                     Name = srv.Name,
                     Description = srq.Description,
                     Requestor = srq.Requestor,
                     Status = srq.Status
                 }).OrderBy(z => z.Service_Id).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

**Viewmodel Example**

```
public class ServiceRequestsVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Service_Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Requestor { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the `@model` directive to use viewmodel with combined properties from both tables:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlinePlatform.Models.ServiceRequestsVM>
```

And the controller should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Service_Request()
{
    var dao = new ServicesDAO();
    return PartialView("Service_Request", dao.ServiceRequestGetAll());
}
```

After completing those steps, the model binding should work altogether.

Comment: And my question is: Why do we need to convert `IQueryable<ServiceRequestsVM>` to `IEnumerable<OnlinePlatform.Models.ServiceRequestsVM>`? Why not just use `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Because OP uses `dao.ServiceRequestGetAll().ToList()` when returning `PartialView`. Using `IEnumerable` is acceptable, but moving `ToList()` inside the method instead.

Comment: Ahh, maybe he/she is new to asp.net mvc. I saw that he/she had got an `IEnumerable`, then converting it to `IQueryable`. Last, converting it to a `List`. But model was using it as `IEnumerable`. lol

Comment: It works. Thank you for the help. I am still new to asp.net mvc. If there is a better way to structure these, please kindly advise

Comment: Glad to hear the problem is solved. The exception message you're encountered previously is because you're returning different viewmodel than expected in `@model` directive, and you should use separate classes for data models and viewmodels. You can mark this issue as solved later.

Answer (score 0):

Get the records by join in two tables using ID..

FYI below,

```
var result= from req in DB.Table_Request
            join service in DB.Table_Service
            on req.Service_id equals  service.id
           select new ServiceRequests
           {
             Name=service.Name,
             ServiceID=req.Service_Id,

             // Followed model Properties 
            }.ToList();
```

Comment: If you have any queries pls ask

Comment: `ServiceRequests` doesn't contain property name `Name`.

Comment: you can add a property name as Name in model class

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a service like this:

*IServiceManager.cs*:

```
public interface IServiceManager
{
    IEnumerable<ServiceRequests> GetAllServiceRequests();

    Service GetService(string serviceId);
}
```

*ServiceManager.cs*:

```
public class ServiceManager : IServiceManager
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _dbContext { get; set; }

    public ServiceRequest(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ServiceRequests> GetAllServiceRequests()
        => _dbContext.ServiceRequests.OrderBy(r => r.Id);

    public Service GetService(string serviceId)
        => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceId) 
               ? _dbContext.Services.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == serviceId) : null;
}
```

*Startup.cs*:

```
services.AddTransient<IServiceManager, ServiceManager>();
```

*Controller*:

```
public ActionResult Service_Request()
{
    return View();
}
```

*Service_Request.cshtml*:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlinePlatform.Models.ServiceRequests>
@inject IServiceManager serviceManager

@foreach (var request in serviceManager.GetAllServiceRequests())
{
    var service = serviceManager.GetService(request.Service_Id);

    <!-- you can use @service.Name here... -->
}
```